# How to implement Notification Image part in IOS from the official documentation in swift code instead of C

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, notifications

I'm trying to implement the last part in the notification image in apple notifications integration [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration)

This is the C Code in the documentation:

```
- // Modify the notification content here...
- self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.title];

- self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
+ [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent withContentHandler:contentHandler];
```

I want to convert it to swift code so i can use it in my Project ImageNotification.swift

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the Firebase [swift documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging) it should probably look something like this:

```
Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(self.bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
```